# Reverse entire dictionary items

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I know this may be a simple question but I'm having trouble reversing my dictionary. All the solutions I've seen haven't been working for me. I have a dictionary where the keys are strings and the values are either None or type int. I want to reverse the order so the last (key, value) pair is first and vice versa.

For example:

```
d = {"pointA": 100, "pointB": 140, "pointC": None, "pointD: None}
```

I want to reverse the dictionary to:

```
reversed_d = {"pointD": None, "pointC": None, "pointB": 140, "pointA": 100}
```

I've tried `sorted(d.items(), reverse=True)` and `reversed(sorted(d.items()))` 
but I got an error of:

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I sort a dictionary by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/how-do-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-value). You may first need to iterate through your dictionary and confirm the type and convert None to np.nan.

Comment: What is the next step after sorting? Order of dictionary is less important.

Comment: Hey Austin, After sorting I want to loop over the keys and values and update them depending on specific events. I already looped over them in its current order but now I need to loop over them reversed.

Comment: Hey Trenton, I attempted the code {k:v for k, v in sorted(d.items(), key=lambda item: item[1])} but I got an error of TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'dict' and 'dict'

Answer (score 1):

You could do it this way.

Loop =>

```
for k,v in reversed(list(d.items())):
```

or just

```
reversed_d = reversed(list(d.items()))
```

Comment: The for loop works only when I print k and v. When I try to store them into a dict it returns the memory address instead of its inputs. Likewise in your example: reversed_d returns a memory address for me. Ex: <function reverse_dict at 0x000001B1885A1C80> or <list_reverseiterator object at 0x0000029E4DE7DCC0>

Comment: @David you just need to cast it to an dict like =>

```
reversed_d = dict(reversed(list(d.items())))
```

Answer (score 0):

since dictionaries are ordered by insertion order of the keys (since `python 3.6`, guaranteed since `python 3.7`), you can reverse the keys:

```
d = {"pointA": 100, "pointB": 140, "pointC": None, "pointD": None}

for k in reversed(d):
    print(k)
```

From there, you can build a new dictionary by inserting key values in the reversed order, or create a generator to access the `(Key, value)` pairs in that order.